# Cannot send password request reminder using Flutter connected with Parse-server

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-server

Hello i have app written in flutter which uses data from parse server.
According to flutter doc:

```
    /// Reset password
response = await user.requestPasswordReset();
if (response.success) {
  user = response.result;
}
```

I'd like to send e-mail using my parser with change password link.
When i press button with that function assigned - i get information: "E-mail sent"
On flutter side i'm getting that output:

```
 Function: ParseApiRQ.requestPasswordReset
I/flutter (28247): Status Code: 200
I/flutter (28247): Payload: {"className":"_User","email":"testazaz@gmail.com"}
```

On parser side i have installed something like this:
[simple-parse-smtp-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-parse-smtp-adapter) Configured as doc says.

I don't getting any Error/Info logs from parser. Can you tell me how to configure it properly? Maybe you know other way - how to connect flutter with parser to send e-mail verification or password change e-mails.

Comment: What is happening? The email never arrive? Can you share the mail adapter configuration that you have in place?

Comment: E-mail never arrive [Code here](https://pastebin.com/UEy2XFGf)

Comment: Can you double check your email smtp settings? That's the only thing that come up on my mind.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo i've tried many variations, do you have any idead how should it look like? I've set google acc to accept smpt and dangerous apps. Tried also with other mail hosting.

Comment: In your User class data, does is the username equal to the email?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo it wasn't but i changed it for test and it still didn't get email.

Comment: Maybe you should try to run parse server with verbose: true and see if there is any useful information on the logs. You can also try other email adapters.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo if i set verbose to true i get like 80MB log text file in couple seconds, there's no way to read anything

Comment: Here's my flutter output:
`I/flutter (18556): 
I/flutter (18556):  http://IP:3000/mocdev1/requestPasswordReset
I/flutter (18556): ╰--
I/flutter (18556): ╭-- Parse Response
I/flutter (18556): Class: _User
I/flutter (18556): Function: ParseApiRQ.requestPasswordReset
I/flutter (18556): Status Code: 200
I/flutter (18556): Payload: {"className":"_User","email":"mail@gmail.com"}
I/flutter (18556): ╰-- 
I/flutter (18556):`

When i click in this link i get this message:
`{"error":"unauthorized"}`

Comment: Have you checked if your sever has open output port for the port of your smtp server?

Comment: I checked 465 and it's unlocked, but i guess it can be used by other app because we have other services hosted on this server that send e-mails (websites, databases etc.). So i cannot disable them, is there any other way to use te other port? I tought google requires this one.

Comment: Different services using the same port for outputting should not be a problem. I really don't know why your email is not going out. Maybe you should try a different mail adapter so we can at least know if that's something wrong with parse setup or if that's something wrong with the simple mail adapter setup.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo i used [another one](https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template), problem is the same, i noticed in flutter debug output this line: 
`curl -X POST -H 'content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' -H 'user-agent: Flutter Parse SDK 3.1.0' -H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: HERE ID' -H 'X-Parse-Master-Key: HERE KEY' -d '{"email":"XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"}' http://myIPhere:3000/mocdev1/requestPasswordReset`
When i copy this and paste into my centos7 I'm getting empty tab {}.

Comment: It looks actually right: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#requesting-a-password-reset

Comment: You should not use master key from the client though (it is not the problem, but you should improve on that for security reasons)

Comment: What's the new adapter you are using?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo this one: [https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template](https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template)

Comment: Would you mind to try out another one that is not via smtp? There is a list here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#email-verification-and-password-reset

Comment: I've tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-generic-email-adapter) parse-server-generic-email-adapter it doesn't work but I'm not sure if i configured it properly.
And i found verbose of simple-parse-smpt-adapter [here](https://pastebin.com/xihbxRqM) Does it say something helpful?

Comment: I think this adapter also uses smtp. If you can try another one, like mandrill or SendGrid... Also, about the verbose, it would be helpful if you could get the logs from the server side.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo ok i'll try with another one, how to get server side logs?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Ok, it finally worked with [Sendgrid Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-sendgrid-adapter) Thanks for advices and patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple days i finally resolved this problem with help of @DaviMacêdo.
I implemented [Sendgrid Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-sendgrid-adapter).
In your parse node-modules folder install this module using cmd:

```
npm i parse-server-sendgrid-adapter
```

Remember to require module at the top of the file:

```
var SimpleSendGridAdapter = require('parse-server-sendgrid-adapter');

var api = new ParseServer({
  ...,
  emailAdapter: SimpleSendGridAdapter({
    apiKey: 'sendgridApiKey',
    fromAddress: 'fromEmailAddress',
  })
});
```

You can get [api key here](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys)
and set up [sender e-mail here](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth)

I hope it helps saving much time for others facing the same problem!